# Select all rows between two specific strings in a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Must Have:**

I have a large sorted dataframe and created an `event` column based on some logic, see below:

**data**=

[image]

The column goes like `start` --> `some events` --> `end`. I want to select all rows between each `start` and `end` and **ignore** anything between the last `end` and next `start`, and continue iterating over this until I have all my `valid` events. Something like below:

[image]

Below are the steps I have tried so far but was unsuccessful-- tried creating a range of indexes and **dynamically** pass these multiple ranges:

**Method 1:**

```
idx_start = data.index[data.event == 'start']
#RESULT = Int64Index([0, 9], dtype='int64')

idx_end = data.index[data.event == 'end']
#RESULT:Int64Index([6, 14], dtype='int64')

data.loc[np.r_[map(range,list(zip(idx_start,idx_end)))],:]
#Which is supposed to show in above case 
data.loc[np.r_[range(0,6),range(9,14)],:]
```

[image]

But I want to dynamically show above result instead of having to write the specific indexes manually.

**Method2:**

I have also tried using some type of filtering that I saw online, but not sure how to work with it:

`pd.factorize(data['event'].isin(['start','end']).iloc[::-1].cumsum().sort_index())[0]`

**Nice To Have:**

It would be great if I could create a counter flag for each `start` and `end` occurrence and anything between last `end` and next `start` should be flagged as `NA`:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One of my friend just helped me with the `Must Have` part and it is working! Just posting this below for reference. Please feel free to solve the `Nice To Have` part showing increments instead of a single value. Thank you!

```
idx_start = data.index[data.event == 'start']
idx_end = data.index[data.event == 'end']
good = list(zip(list(idx_start), list(idx_end)))#required sequences

#unpack list of list
g2 = [list(range(x[0],x[1]+1)) for x in good]

#data.iloc[np.r_[[y for x in g2 for y in x]]]#If you want to return just the valid dataset

l =[y for x in g2 for y in x]

data['mark'] = np.where((data.index.isin(l)),1,None)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data.loc[np.r_[*map(lambda x: range(*x),list(zip(idx_start,idx_end)))],:]
```

**Update**: unpacking does not work with `np.r_` and I don't know why.

So here is the alternative:

```
t = [range(*i) for i in zip(idx_start, idx_end)]
data.loc[np.r_[t[0], t[1]],:]
```

Comment: Hello, it says invalid syntax for the asterisk. Could you help me how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's a bit late, maybe I can come with a simple solution for those who were facing the same problem (as me):

```
#creating a dummy dataframe:
list_events = ["start", "event1", "event2", "event3", "end"]*3
data = pd.DataFrame({"event": list_events})

#Output:
     event
0    start
1   event1
2   event2
3   event3
4      end
5    start
6   event1
7   event2
8   event3
9      end
10   start
11  event1
12  event2
13  event3
14     end

idx_start = data.index[data.event == "start"]  # setting indexes for "start" occurrence
#Output: Int64Index([0, 5, 10], dtype='int64')

idx_end = data.index[data.event == "end"]  # setting indexes for "end" occurrence
#Output: Int64Index([4, 9, 14], dtype='int64')

# creates list of subsets of dataframe between "start" and "end" occurrences
subset_df = []
for i_start, i_end in zip(idx_start, idx_end):
    subset_df.append(df.iloc[(i_start+1):i_end, :])

# concatenates all the sub-dataframes
merged_df = pd.concat(subset_df)
```

I hope this helps someone.